# Start dialogue in botframework webchat

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, botframework, web-chat

I have a question with the webchat, when I publish my bot in azure and I test it test in Web Chat, the bot always starts greeting me with the `OnMembersAddedAsync` method, but when I deploy it on my server using `<iframe>` it has to be the user say hello first so that the `OnMembersAddedAsync` is activated and what I want it to start alone without the user having to type anything, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webchat documentation addresses this:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/docs/WELCOME_MESSAGE.md#tokens-user-ids-and-iframes